# Yup Import Problems in React

Tags: reactjs, yup

Can someone help me, I'm going through the React-Bootstrap Validation example that uses Yup in the following way (it's [this page if you scroll down to Validation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/)):

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  firstName: yup.string().required(),
  lastName: yup.string().required(),
  username: yup.string().required(),
  city: yup.string().required(),
  state: yup.string().required(),
  zip: yup.string().required(),
  terms: yup.bool().required().oneOf([true], 'Terms must be accepted'),
});
```

It doesn't show how Yup is imported. But I import it properly as follows in my JS file:

```
import * as Yup from 'yup';
```

and the following different version from a different example, with capitalized e.g. `Yup.string()..` works for me:

```
  validationSchema={Yup.object({
     firstName: Yup.string()
       .max(15, 'Must be 15 characters or less')
       .required('Required'),
     lastName: Yup.string()
       .max(20, 'Must be 20 characters or less')
       .required('Required'),
     email: Yup.string().email('Invalid email address').required('Required'),
   })}
```

When I try to make that Bootstrap-React Tutorial work with their lowercased versions,

```
  Line 7:16:   'yup' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 8:14:   'yup' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 9:13:   'yup' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 10:13:  'yup' is not defined  no-undef
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not import it as lowercase? e.g. `import * as yup from 'yup';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about `import * as yup from 'yup'` ?

Answer (score 0):

in my case the problem was the Visual Studio code, I just closed and reopened it, and finally yup was imported.